# Use Image View to open new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im creating an app and I require an image to open up a new activity in android studios but it doesnt seem to work. Can anyone see any problems with the code below?

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.table);
imgview.bringToFront();
imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Options.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: are you receiving intent in `options.class`?

Comment: Does `Options` extend Activity?

Comment: *doesnt seem to work...* is the app crashing? we need to see the error if any

Comment: Is your app crashing?

Comment: provide full code of both classes.

Comment: Is **Options.class** declared at your Manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please rearrange you code to look like :

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.table);
    imgview.bringToFront();
    imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Options.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

**Be sure that you Options class extend AppCompatActivity**

```
public class Options extends AppCompatActivity {
**STUFF**
}
```

make sure that Options is declared in the AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<activity
android:name=".Options
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the ImageView and its code inside the onCreate() method.
Since you have a class named as `Options.class` A class from `BitmapFactory.Options.class` also exists, so please check your imports.

Comment: When i do this, the app crashes

Comment: check your Manifest, if Options.class is declared?

Comment: Check the id of your ImageView, whether you are pointing to the correct component.

Comment: @Gothdo, sorry to take your time. Many thanks for it. I thought it was not so clear to me. Best.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view1){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Don't forget to get Intent in the `Option.class` activity:

```
public class Options extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
    Intent intent0 = getIntent();
}
}
```

Also add `android:clickable:"true"` in XML code of the `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ss"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

and `Option` should be declared in `Menifest.xml` as:

```
 </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Options"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

try ImageButton instead of ImageView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.k);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Options.class );
    startActivity(myIntent);

  }
}
```

In your new Activity XML, try this. **Dont Forget to put the image source(android:src="@drawable/k") or you will get a Nullpointerexception**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirmesh.problem1.Options">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:src="@drawable/k"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```